# Android Volley Caching - Get Response by URL and Request Body

Tags: android, url, caching

From my experimenting so far, it appears that Volley accesses its cache based on the URL alone.  I would like to know if it also can determine which response it should return based on the combination of URL and request body data.

Is there a setting for this, or and extension point where I can implement this myself.

I don't see anywhere that the request body data is returned in the NetworkResponse object, or I would do the check in the parseNetworkResponse method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `Request.getCacheKey()` method to include request body as well, when implementing your custom request.